# Is the orthogonal polar factor the unique retraction $\operatorname{GL}_n^+ \to \operatorname{SO}_n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices, retraction

$\newcommand{\psym}{\text{Psym}_n}$
$\newcommand{\sym}{\text{sym}}$
$\newcommand{\Sym}{\operatorname{Sym}}$
$\newcommand{\Skew}{\operatorname{Skew}}$
$\renewcommand{\skew}{\operatorname{skew}}$
$\newcommand{\GLp}{\operatorname{GL}_n^+}$
$\newcommand{\SO}{\operatorname{SO}_n}$

This might be silly, but I wonder:

> Let $F:\GLp \to \SO$ be a continuous retract. Is it true that $F$ must be the orthogonal polar factor, i.e. $F(A)=O$, where $A=OP,O \in \SO,P\in\psym$. Does anything changes if we assume $F$ is a deformation retract? Or if it is a *smooth* deformation retract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retractions are a very "soft" concept so there is a huge number of those. Take any continuous function $f:PSym_n\to SO_n$ and define $F_f(A):=O\cdot f(P)$ for $A=OP$. Then this is clearly a retraction and it even is a defomormation retraction, which is smooth if $f$ is smooth.

Comment: Thanks, I was just thinking something similar myself: we can take e.g. $F(A)= O\det A$ or $F(A)= O\frac{\| A\|}{\sqrt n}$ or variations on these. However, both of these retractions are "proportional" to the orthogonal polar factor. A more interesting question is: are there retractions $GL^+ \to SO$ which are not proportional to it? (By your construction, it suffices to find a continuous non constant map $f:Psym \to SO$ which is the identity on $SO$. Is it trivial such a map exists?)

Comment: In fact, therer are no conditions on the map $f$, so lots of such maps exist